# Connected vs Disconnected Architecture in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

what are advantages & disadvantages of connected & disconnected  Architecture (database) over one another  in asp.net ?

Comment: By that do you mean the difference between using a DataSet & DataAdapter versus using a DataReader?

Answer (score 12):

In disconnected architecture a **DataSet** is used for retrieving data from the database. Then no need for maintaining the connection also. All the operations can be performed with the data once retrieved. It won't cause traffic problems while working with the data.

In connected architecture a **DataReader** is used for retrieving data from the database. Here a connection is always maintained. Update, Delete, Read and Select operations can be performed  as the data is accessed in the database, so that a connection must be be maintained. This can cause traffic problems.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to ASP.NET, a "disconnected" architecture usually refers to one in which data is downloaded to the ASP.NET app's memory in infrequent bulk requests and stored in the cache for later processing. This avoids frequent trips to the database, thus eliminating one of the major I/O obstacles. In a site where data is frequently queried but not updated, this can be a significant performance improvement, if your server has the memory to support the caching of the data.

There is of course the possibility that you're referencing the use of something like Google Gears, but I haven't heard of that being used much in the ASP.NET world. Anything's possible, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer indirectly had tell me why I was missing the point about disconnected in this tutorial http://aspalliance.com/1866_Building_Reports_using_ASPNET_and_Crystal_Reports__Part_3__An_Invoice_Report_Using_Disconnected_Data.all

Answer (score 2):

before understanding about this implementation you have to understand how database system is implemented in .NET frame work. in .NET ,the ADO.NET is responsible for data handling and in ADO.NET there is dataset, data adapter and database.

dataset is a temporary placement in the client's memory for holding the data sent from the database. data adapter is an intermediate party that sends and receives data back and forth ,I meant it sends data from dataset and then database server sends the result from the database to the dataset and this process is done through data adapter.

usually data adapter uses a connection to connect with the database in order start the transaction and in Disconnected data architecture ,this connection is closed as soon as the data is passed from/to database . the biggest advantage is the security because when the connection is always opened anyone can access to the database because it's always opened. in connected one, the user has to authenticate again and again and open the connection again and again whenever the transaction is started so this reduces the performance and increases work load specially when there is a lot of transactions but it secures the database from unauthorized parties.

Answer (score 1):

connected data needs connection to be created to access
hence slower while disconnected is in memory data that's
faster access.

to access connected data you use ADO.NET whereas for
disconnected you do not use.

disconnected-data can be accessed from multiple tables in a
dataset.
connected- .NET runtime creates an instance of the datatable
to hold data.

in disconnected data you can create a window to the
datatable in the form of a dataview used to sort and filter
data. which cannot be done in connected data access

connected you need to use a read only forward only data
reader, disconnected you cannot.

disconnected data in a dataset can be serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score -3):

asp.net is a server side technology designed for a server to process requests for pages. The very nature of ASP.NET requires a connected model.

Could you clarify what you mean by "disconnected"?